# Why Room LiveData not returning the values?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have a problem with Room that return `LiveData`.

I create `Dao` with function to returns list of data. I suppose to return as `LiveData`. But, it doesn't work as expected.

`Dao` function

```kotlin
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM AllocationPercentage WHERE id IN (:ids)")
fun getByIds(ids: List<Long>): LiveData<List<AllocationPercentageWithDetails>>
```

Here is how I observe it inside the ViewModel:

```kotlin
class AllocationViewModel(
    private val getAllocationByIdUseCase: GetAllocationByIdUseCase,
    private val getDetailByIdUseCase: GetAllocationPercentageByIdUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    var allocationUiState: LiveData<AllocationUiState> = MutableLiveData()
        private set

    var allocationPercentageUiState: LiveData<List<AllocationPercentageUiState>> = MutableLiveData()
        private set

    val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<List<AllocationPercentageUiState>>()

    fun getAllocationById(allocationId: Long) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = getAllocationByIdUseCase(allocationId) // LiveData

        allocationUiState = Transformations.map(result) {
            AllocationUiState(allocation = it.allocation)
        }

        mediatorLiveData.addSource(result) { allocation ->
            Log.d(TAG, "> getAllocationById")
            val ids = allocation.percentages.map { percentage -> percentage.id }
            val detailResult: LiveData<List<AllocationPercentageWithDetails>> =
                getDetailByIdUseCase(ids) // LiveData
            allocationPercentageUiState = Transformations.map(detailResult) { details ->
                Log.d(TAG, ">> Transform : $details")
                details.map {
                    AllocationPercentageUiState(
                        id = it.allocationPercentage.id,
                        percentage = it.allocationPercentage.percentage,
                        description = it.allocationPercentage.description,
                        currentProgress = it.allocationPercentage.currentProgress
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `allocationPercentageUiState` is observed by `Fragment`.

```kotlin
    Log.d(TAG, "observeViewModel: ${it?.size}")
    val percentages = it ?: return@observe
    setAllocationPercentages(percentages) // update UI
}

allocationViewModel.mediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {}
```

And `getDetailByIdUseCase` just a function which directly return result from Dao.

```kotlin
class GetAllocationPercentageByIdUseCase(private val repository: AllocationPercentageRepository) {
    operator fun invoke(ids: List<Long>): LiveData<List<AllocationPercentageWithDetails>> {
        return repository.getAllocationPercentageByIds(ids)
    }
}
```

Any idea why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Combining `var` with LiveData or MutableLiveData doesn't make sense. It defeats the purpose of using LiveData. If something comes along and observes the original LiveData that you have in that property, it will never receive anything. It will have no way of knowing there's a new LiveData instance it should be observing instead.

I can't exactly tell you how to fix it because your code above is incomplete, so I can't tell what you're trying to do in your mapping function, or whether it is called in some function vs. during ViewModel initialization.

Comment: Oh, thank you for mentioning that. I distracted with another LiveData that I thought it is working fine. But when I debug, it is not. 

Let me recheck the implementation.